# Apt-get 403 Forbidden, but accessible in the browser

Tags: apt, ppa

I've noticed that running `apt-get update` recently has resulted in quite a few ppa's returning "403 Forbidden".  In and effort to clean them up I had a look:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The strange things is, if I copy these URLs into my browser I can access the files just fine.  Why would apt-get report "403 Forbidden" if they're still accessible?  I tried re-adding the ppa through `add-apt-repository` which downloads the signing key again, and it still reported "403 Forbidden".

Comment: i don't have squid or any other proxy, and still get these errors

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So it turns out this is an issue with squid-deb-proxy.  Unfortunately it doesn't add PPAs and other repositories and just fails with an rather unexpected 403 error.

You can fix this by adding the repositories to the config file:

**`/etc/squid-deb-proxy/mirror-dstdomain.acl`**

```
# launchpad personal package archives (disabled by default) 
ppa.launchpad.net                                           
private-ppa.launchpad.net
```

Of course, uninstalling squid-deb-proxy also works around the issue:

```
apt-get remove squid-deb-proxy
```

Comment: For the curious, this means uncommenting the `ppa.launchpad.net` line in `/etc/squid-deb-proxy/mirror-dstdomain.acl.d/10-default`.

Comment: Don't forget to `sudo service squid-deb-proxy restart` after doing this.

Comment: I was trying `sudo service squid-deb-proxy reload` but this did not appears to reload the dstdomain.acl, a service restart was required as said by [Power-Inside](http://askubuntu.com/questions/303150/apt-get-403-forbidden-but-accessible-in-the-browser#comment1100340_307379) above.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using proxy?

I have often experience this error, even when using main server.I noticed that this happens when apt-get process breaks for some reason. For instance when running `apt-get update` downloading of some file coudn't be completed. You will there after get 403 error for that particular file.

I learned that these partially downloaded files (I am not sure if they are exactly the files) during apt-get update are stored in `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/`

So I did
`sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*`(deleted all files in the directory)

After  this I din't get the 403 error.

If you are getting the error when running `apt-get install` or `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade`

try `sudo rm -r /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*`

Answer (score 1):

I use intelligent mirror. I had to `apt clean all` then remove my previously downloaded deb files in my squid's `/var/spool/squid3/intelligentmirror/deb` directory to get it to continue.