# How to fix forbidden error in ubuntu18.04 LTS apt-get update?

Tags: apt, server, dns, update-manager, proxy

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.174 80]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.174 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.174 80]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.174 80]
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: Check this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169657/unable-to-update-or-install-anything-after-moving-to-another-country). If it does not help you, it may be that your router blocks some traffic.

Comment: Can able to ping google and other website but unable to access. Is any proxy blocking in server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure proxy for APT?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt). Point apt at your proxy instead of archive.ubuntu.com

Comment: but all links are showing as 403 forbidden. will check and get back

Comment: Maybe this can help, too: [Apt-get 403 Forbidden, but accessible in the browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303150/apt-get-403-forbidden-but-accessible-in-the-browser).